# Bash Script "another way of assigning array variables"

Tags: arrays, variables

It's easy to find this example around:

> Yet another way of assigning array variables...
>
> array_name=([xx]=XXX [yy]=YYY ...)

And then they proced with an easy example.

So, if I do:

```
REM=( [a]=x [1]=y )
echo ${REM[a]}
echo ${REM[1]}
```

It returns x and y, as I want.

But if I do:

```
REM=( [a]=x [b]=y )
echo ${REM[a]}
echo ${REM[b]}
```

It returns y and y. Why this happens and how could I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your second example has only one key, which is zero. If you echo the keys for it, you'll see this:

```sh
pax> echo ${!REM[@]}
0
```

Additionally, if you echo the keys for the first example, you'll see `0 1`, *not* `a 1` as you might expect.

And this has to do with this little snippet from the `bash` man-page (with my emphasis):

> An ***indexed*** array is created automatically if any variable is assigned to using the syntax `name[subscript]=value`. The subscript is treated ***as an arithmetic expression that must evaluate to a number.***

But you don't *want* an indexed array, since the keys there must be numeric. You need an *associative* array, where the keys can be strings, and the solution can be found in the same man-page:

> To explicitly declare an indexed array, use `declare -a name`. Associative arrays are created using `declare -A name`.

Hence, you should be using:

```sh
pax> declare -A REM            # Force associative array, not indexed,
pax> REM=( [a]=1 [b]=42 )      # so that keys are strings.

pax> echo ${!REM[@]}           # Keys now correct (though arbitrary order).
b a

pax> echo ${REM[a]}:${REM[b]}  # Values correct as well.
1:42
```